# Ruby test raise_if_conflicts error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I created `sample_test.rb` to run Minitest.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class SampleTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_sample
    assert_equal 'RUBY', 'ruby'.upcase
  end
end
```

I tried to run `sample_test.rb` but I got this error.

```
Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2291:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate railties-5.1.3, because activesupport-5.1.2 conflicts with activesupport (= 5.1.3) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1411:in `activate'
...
```

I tried `gem cleanup` and `gem uninstall activesupport -v "5.1.3"` but I couldn't solve this problem.

My ruby version is `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]`

Could you give me your hand please.

Comment: maybe try bundle exec?

Comment: I could solve this problem to add bundle exec.I tried `gem install bundler` and `bundle init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5.1.2 version in activesupport-5.1.2 is the version outlier. I'd suggest `gem uninstall`ing that one.

Also, you can try `bundle exec` as suggested in Max's comment. Also, `bundle doctor` may give you some helpful information.

Comment: I uninstalled activesupport-5.1.2 but I got error again almost same messgae as what I got before. The difference is only version of activesupport like activesupport-5.0.3. I continued to delete all activesupport verison what I got from error messages, but finally I got different error so I stopped to uninstall gems.

I think I haven't solved underlying problem but to get straight to the point, I could solve this error by adding `bundle exec` as Max said.
Before to add `bundle exec` I executed `gem install bundler` and `bundle init` then edit gem file to add `gem minitest`